# How do you shoot with the Panzer Tank in Commandos?

Tags: commandos

How do you shoot with the Panzer Tank? The enemies are able to shoot with it, yet when I try to use it, clicking only moves the tank around.

This is for *Commandos: Behind Enemy Lines*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These controls are used for the Panzer II Tank, the Panzer IV Tank, and the SDFKZ 231.

Normally, left clicking will move the tank around, and will use a cursor with a steering wheel on it:

[image: Commandos - Panzer II Tank with move cursor]

*Note:* If you aren't even able to move around, make sure the Driver is in the tank and currently selected. Although others can sit in the vehicle, he is the only one that can operate it.

If you want to shoot with the tank, hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key; your cursor will change to a crosshair instead:

[image: Commandos - Panzer II Tank with shoot crosshair]

With the key held down, click where you want the tank to fire. Due to these controls, it is difficult to fire and move at the same time (and was likely done purposefully).

Comment: To add to that: seems like the tank will only use machinegun for short range and only use the main gun for the longer ranges. So if you want to fire the main gun just go further from your target.